# Leaflet + google maps having some zooming issues

Tags: google-maps, leaflet, mapbox

I tried integrating google maps tile layer into leaflet using leaflet-google plugin. Everything loads fine, but when i try to zoom in/out, first my custom feature layer zooms and then the google map tile layer zooms. Why don't they zoom together?

```
 var map = new L.Map('map', {center: new L.LatLng(18.93718 , 72.79366), zoom: 10});
  var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP');
  map.addLayer(googleLayer);
```

and I am adding my feature layer by:

```
L.geoJson(inputgeoJson, {
    style: style,
    onEachFeature: onEachFeature
}).addTo(map);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The Google layer in Leaflet is a hack (a [possibly illegal one](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins/issues/48)), and involves using the Google Maps API within Leaflet. Since Leaflet and the Google Maps API have different zoom transition animations, you see this effect. You could use Google tiles directly in Leaflet, but that's definitely be illegal, not just maybe.